# Wifi not working on démo MacBook air 2013

Tags: wifi, macbook, release-jolnir

[FR]
Bonjour,
Je viens de télécharger elementary os et l'utilise depuis la clé USB de 8Go sur mon MacBook air 2013. C'est mon premier contact avec Linux.
Je n'ai pas de wifi sur la version de démonstration et me suis donc connecté par câble à mon téléphone pour partager la connexion.
J'ai ensuite essayé tous les tutos trouvables je crois, y compris les trois méthodes [ici](https://subinsb.com/install-realtek-d723-wifi-driver-linux/#download).

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Cette commande me retourne : E : dpkg a été interrompu. Il est nécessaire d'utiliser " sudo dpkg --configure -a" pour corriger le problème.
Ladite commande me donne :
dpkg : erreur : échec de l'écriture de status enregistrement de "apache2-bin" à "/var/lib/dpkg/status" : aucun espace disponible sur le  périphérique.
Je suis très très déçu.

Une idée ?
Merci d'avance

[EN]
Hello,
I just downloaded elementary os and use it from the 8GB USB key on my MacBook air 2013. This is my first contact with Linux.
I don't have wifi on the demo version so I connected via cable to my phone to share the connection.
I then tried every tutorial I could find I think, including the three methods [here](https://subinsb.com/install-realtek-d723-wifi-driver-linux/#download).

```
    sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

This command returns: E: dpkg has been interrupted. It is necessary to use "sudo dpkg --configure -a" to correct the problem.
The said command gives me:
dpkg: error: failed to write status record from "apache2-bin" to "/var/lib/dpkg/status": no space available on the device.
I am very very disappointed.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

```
[1]: https://subinsb.com/install-realtek-d723-wifi-driver-linux/#download
```

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Answer (score 0):

[FR] Bienvenue sur linux !
Sans aller aussi loin que les solutions proposées dans le lien, après installation de eOS Odin sur un Imac et branchement par ethernet, il m'a suffit d'aller dans le Centre d'applications pour mettre à jour le système et installer les pilotes recommandés.

Je suppose que les pilotes pour périphériques wifi des Macs ne sont pas disponibles dans le live install... En utilisation live depuis la clef usb, je pense que l'on peut faire la même manip, et qu'elle reste persistente après un reboot dessus.

Si tu choisis de l'installer ou de faire un dual boot, il y a plein de sites qui suggèrent quoi installer pour améliorer certains aspects comme l'accès a plus de logiciels etc, mais ça peut dépendre de l'usage fait de l'ordinateur, Elementary Os se voulant facile d'utilisation, il propose un environnement épuré et simplifié protégeant l'experience utilisateur des débutants :)

[EN]
Welcome to linux !
Without going as far as the solutions offered in the link, after installing eOS Odin on an Imac and connecting by ethernet, I only had to go to the App Center to update the system and install the recommended drivers, including wireless one.

I assume that the drivers for wifi devices of Macs are not available in the live install... Using eOS live from the usb stick, I think you can do the same procedure, it should be persistent.

If you choose to install it or do a dual boot, there are plenty of sites that suggest what to install to improve some aspects like access to more softwares etc, but it may depend on the use made of the computer, Elementary Os is intended to be easy to use, it offers a clean and simplified environment safeguarding more advanced use for newbies :)

Comment: Merci de la  réponse rapide. J'ai bien essayé de faire les mises à jour système (plus de 240) mais elles n'aboutissent pas." Échec de la mise à jour des Mises a jour système. Cela peut être dû à des logiciels externes ou compilés manuellement". D'ailleurs je reçois un message d'alerte des que je vais dans les mises a jour : erreur lors de la récupération des mises a jour. Ceci peut être provoqué par un dépôt externe ajoute manuellement ou un fichier corrompu. S'en suit une longue decscritpion sous "détails". Vous pensez que ca fonctionnerait si j'effacais le disque MacOS ?

Comment: Effacer le disque Mac ne serait pas la solution ;) 

Si les mises a jour ne démarent pas, c'est peut etre lié au live USB. En recherchant,, je vois qu'en fait le live USB ne permet pas la persistence sans une procédure spécialement faite pour ...Peut être serait il préferable de faire une vraie installation sur un disque dur externe de façon à tester eOS sans perndre le risque de perdre le Mac OS ?

Comment: Si le live USB le permet, il devrait être possible de charger manuellement le pilote nécessaire, mais il faut donc d'abord savoir lequel 
'  sudo lshw -class network -short ' dans un terminal dira le nom du périphérique wifi (les cartes wifi commencent par w, dans mon cas wlp4s0  = BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n)

En regardant si le Centre d'applications a pu déterminer le pilote nécessaire - dans mon cas bcmwl-kernel-source et voir si on peut l'installer en ligne de commande (' sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source ' dans mon cas)